# Grammatical error in the SE Content Policy

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, policy

[Content Policy - Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy/)

In the second paragraph, there is this sentence, error bolded by me:

> We reserve the right to immediately suspend, without notice, any content, account, or IP address which we determine to be submitting spam or **potentially other** damaging or disruptive content the Network.

To me, at least, the bolded words should be swapped around to make sense. There should also be a "to" in that sentence:

> We reserve the right to immediately suspend, without notice, any content, account, or IP address which we determine to be submitting spam or **other potentially** damaging or disruptive content **to** the Network.

#### Can this be fixed?

I found that these problems made me read it a few times before actually understanding it.

Comment: You're in the right place

Comment: Isn't it the point of legal documents to be confusing? :P

Comment: I disagree that the "other" and "potentially" need to be swapped.  But "to" is definitely missing

Comment: I disagree. We apply something **to** something.

Comment: OP is right, but it could be. _Potentially other_ (sometimes we invert sequence to make an accent on something very important).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Phrasing updated.